# Are there any disadvantages of bootstrapping Arch linux against installing it from a bootable medium?

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

While I have looked up the definitions and meaning of 'bootstrapping' and 'chroot' I am not entirely sure about the difference it would make once the installation is complete.

Since the image size is about 500MB for the latter method and only about 150MB for the former one I am sure it would make some sort of difference which may or may not be significant.

As is evident, I don't have much of an experience with Unix. *Currently running Ubuntu 16.04*, I decided to just go for Arch Linux and learn the rest as I proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will make no difference once the installation is complete, both [bootstrapping](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_existing_Linux) from an existing system and [installing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide) from a bootable medium will give you the same end result. There's just not much point in bootstrapping if you have the option of using an installation medium.

Arch is ***not*** designed to be "user friendly" or easy. It is aimed at technically savvy users who want to have a system that is tweaked exactly as they want. If you don't have much experience using Linux, you really, really, should do the simplest installation possible and that's using an installation medium.

The first time I installed Arch, about two or three years ago, I had already been using Linux for more than 15 years. I was quite comfortable with the command line, and relatively knowledgeable about Linux. I had installed various distributions on at least a dozen or more different machines. Despite all this, I still had to try two or three times before I got it right.

Arch's documentation is probably the best in the Linux world. If you follow the instructions *to the letter*, you will be fine (I had to redo it because I thought a couple of things weren't that important, don't make that mistake).

If you follow the guide, everything should work, but seeing as it isn't the simplest process to begin with, don't make your life more complicated by choosing to bootstrap. It just adds some extra steps that don't give you much benefit and are a few more places where you can get something wrong.

Comment: I cannot find any pendrive around me, so instead of waiting a couple more days to get it from amazon, I decided to go with bootstrapping for the heck of it. While not a lot of experience but I am familiar with linux and have been using Ubuntu for a few years on and off. I have another laptop as well which will allow me to continue my works if I mess anything up. I will definitely keep it in my mind to follow everything to the letter. Thank you for your helpful response.